# Как указать в LayoutParams размер в dp?

Tags: java, android, layout

Собственно весь вопрос описан в заголовкие:). Могу добавить код:

```
 LinearLayout.LayoutParams lParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(x,y);
```

Тута нужно в dp сделать, объясните пожалуйста :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Нашел, мб кому пригодиться:

```
int dip = 40; // сколько dp нам нужно
float px = TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, dip,  getResources().getDisplayMetrics()); // преобразуем dp в px
int k = (int)px; // опять преобразуем, вот только тут я не знаю, правильно ли я делаю, думаю в коментариях скажут
LinearLayout.LayoutParams lParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(k,k); // вставляем
```